# Import 1.2 GB database to phpmyadmin xampp and having error

Tags: php, import, database

I have been trying to import my magento website database which size is 1.2 gb in phpmyadmin xampp and having error

''You probably tried to upload a file that is too large. Please refer to documentation for a workaround for this limit.''

I did below things to solve my problem but nothing work.

In *php.ini*

```
max_execution_time = 300 
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 1200M
upload_max_filesize = 1100M
post_max_size = 1100M
```

Used bigdump and having this error **"access denied for user localhost using password yes"**

Is any one has solution of my problem?

Comment: You should clean your database first before dumping it. It will a lot smaller. Chances are you have log tables that are taking space.

Comment: first check the user/pass and its privileges, by default user is `root` with no password but you may have updated/created new.

Comment: You might have changed settings in `php.ini`, but are you sure they took effect? Always check `phpinfo()` to make sure your settings are correct, don't rely on what the config file tells you.

Comment: Don't use phpMyAdmin. Just that simple. When you're working with large datasets like this, use SCP/SFTP to move the file and the command line to import it. phpMyAdmin is a bloated slow GUI with timeout issues and import hiccup problems when it comes to dealing with large amounts of data. I had to laugh uproariously when our "Web Developer" spent three days trying to import a database that I had done in the time it took to sftp transfer it plus about 10 minutes while the mySQL command line slurped it into the database.

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove (or reduce) your log files that will really make your backup file smaller, as @brentwpeterson said. You can do so by typing below command in your magento root

`php -f shell/log.php clean --days 30` to keep 30 days log, keep it whatever you like

2. Backup the database now
   `mysqldump -u[username] -p [database_name] > db.sql`
3. Import it. Make sure your mysql username has all the grant privileges to new database
   `mysql -u[username] -p [new_database_name] < db.sql`

I don't think you can do import easily via PHPmyAdmin as Magento DBs are usually huge. Doing from mysql console/terminal is the best and fastest way to do.

Comment: Thanks for your replies..
Kalpesh.. i am using Xampp shell and try this command for import mysql -u[username] -p [new_database_name] < db.sql 

after copy/paste my password its giving me below error:

Access denied for user username @localhost (using password: Yes)

Comment: How about resetting your mysql password or creating new mysql user with all privileges in phpmyadmin? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272979/php-mysql-on-xampp-password-for-phpmyadmin-and-mysql-connect-different

Comment: but how will i do this.. i dont have mysql installed in localhost/phpmyadmin .. i am trying to import my db from my c:/ folder .. how will i change and create new user

Comment: is there any other way to import db in my localhost.. like how will i do via navicat .. can you please tell me

Comment: @aleshparker that's something you need to figure it out, you can ask in mysql forums/SO site on how to get your mysql password.

Answer (score 0):

**You should use command line for uploading max(100 gb or more) data:**

1. 1.Go to `"C:\xampp\mysql\bin" folder and here you press shift(keyboard) + right click (mouse)` and click on 
   `"Open command window here"`
2. Now you should use this command in command window `mysql -u root -p databasename <"complete path of importing file \databasename.sql"`.
3. Enter Password: `if you have password database user otherwise just Enter`
   Your database take sometimes and then `uploaded successfully....`

Comment: i fallowed you but after pressing enter i did not get anything